# Ignore derived data in gitHub

Tags: xcode, git, github, gitignore

I'm creating an application in swift, when I'm trying to push the application to GitHub it seems to add "derivedData" etc, which I do not want to be added in the git.

I've tried to look around for the `.gitignore` file but cannot find it anywhere.

Do I've to create a new `.gitignore` file? How and where should I place this? What should be ignored? If not, where can I find the file?

I'm tried to look around for this for hours but still no success. So I had to ask you guys for the solution of this.

Thanks.

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: Wait - is the derived data folder in the project folder??? That's wrong and you should start by fixing that.

Comment: @matt Where else should it be located?

Comment: Well it's usually hidden away in your Library.

Comment: @matt Hmm, I cleared the derived data once, thats why I can see it.

Answer (score 0):

Files that start with a dot are hidden in the Finder by default. Press Cmd-Shift-Dot in the Finder to see hidden files and folders.

If you need to create a .gitignore file, go to [gitignore.io](https://www.gitignore.io/). Enter Xcode in the search field and click the Create button. A .gitignore file will be created for you. Copy the contents into a file in a text editor and save the file as `.gitignore`. Add the .gitignore file to your project folder. You can find more detailed information in the following article:

[Telling Git to Ignore Files in Xcode Projects](https://www.meandmark.com/blog/2018/02/telling-git-to-ignore-files-in-xcode-projects/)

To avoid having to create a .gitignore file for each Xcode project you create, you can create a global .gitignore file. Name the file `.gitignore_global` and place it in your user home folder.

Comment: The question is asking specifically about Derived Data

Comment: If you [create a git ignore file for Xcode at gitignore.io](https://www.toptal.com/developers/gitignore/api/xcode), you will see the git ignore file ignores the Derived Data folder.